# ServerSide Sessions safe?

Tags: php, security, session

I'm using (server side, not cookie) sessions in an application that I writing, if the users has not obtained access to the server can I trust the $_SESSION variable or should I verify it's content on every page load?


**Note:**
I'm trying to limit the number of queries to my database and currently I am verifying the data on every page load, and I', thinking that I can probably eliminate the queries, but I want to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can store it in the session safely. You should make sure that the Validation method is safe. (the method you use before storing in the session).

Comment: By the way, it does depend on which information you store in the session. We store our entire User object in the session. This implies we need a 'refresh' method to synchronize session/database data for instance when a User updates its information.

Comment: This is exactly the data I'm currently verifying the users object.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make sure that session is stored in safe place. By default sessions are stored on somewhere like /tmp/ on linux. If user can access your server they can edit the session variables.

You should consider saving sessions to database, and/or adding hash calculation (md5+secret seed) verification to sessions, and always check that session variables are not modified against that hash.

Comment: If there is a "user" on the live web servan and he/she can edit the session files, the ship is already gone. BTW Unkwntech wants to minimize the number of DB queryes + a user might gain access to the database just as "easily" as being able to edit the session files.